find -regex for several extensions
I'm trying to cleanup some files on a Debian 11 machine.
These files live in a subdirectory in:

/tmp/.debrief, or
/opt/site/var/debrief

I can identify them by the extension in their filename:

.debsess,
.slmcrec,
.div, or
.debmeta

I thought using GNU findutil's -regex flag and the -delete flag would be perfect:
find /tmp/.debrief /opt/site/var/debrief \
    -regex '.*\.(?:div|debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)' \
    -delete

But it doesn't seem to match any of the files I see.  Then I realized find doesn't directly implement pcre:
$ find -regextype help
valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, 
‘awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, 
‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.

I'm pretty sure GNU grep doesn't implement capture groups without -E, but egrep does:
$ ls /tmp/.debrief | egrep '.*\.(div|debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)'
1R_camera.div
1R.debmeta
4Ahi_camera.div
4Ahi.debmeta
...

But find still doesn't seem to match those files:
$ find /tmp/.debrief /opt/site/var/debrief \
    -regextype egrep \
    -regex '.*\.(div|debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)'
--no output--

My find version is find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0.
What am I missing?

Edit: Output of egrep per request in the comments:
$ ls /tmp/.debrief | egrep '.*\.(div\debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)' | LC_ALL=C sed -n l
1R.slmcrec$
28.11.debsess$
4Ahi.slmcrec$
Cc7.slmcrec$
dc.slmcrec$
h0M.slmcrec$
hWdxlm.slmcrec$
i79W.slmcrec$
ILWm7b.slmcrec$
izebDM.slmcrec$
K7yUk.slmcrec$
kIziXi.slmcrec$
L4XWy.slmcrec$
M.slmcrec$
NR.slmcrec$
Nz7.slmcrec$
o7qXQ.slmcrec$
oD.slmcrec$
pAupd0.slmcrec$
pwxh.slmcrec$
uCptRo.slmcrec$
vWsP9.slmcrec$
YMYtEi.slmcrec$
zV6.slmcrec$


-o ..........

Ah, if I separate -name clauses with -o (or) it does work!  I'm still wondering why the regex doesn't work though.

It works for me with find (GNU findutils) 4.10.0

Works with Debian12, find 4.9.0: find /tmp/.debrief  -regextype egrep  -regex '.*\.(div|debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)'. What is the output of find --version?

find --version is find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0

And what's the output of ls /tmp/.debrief | egrep '.*\.(div|debmeta|slmcrec|debsess)' | LC_ALL=C sed -n l?

(?:foo|bar) is a perl regex operator. perl regexps is not among the regex flavours supported by GNU find.

Capture groups which can be then back referenced are a feature of basic regex (grep) not extended regex. In standard ERE (...) does grouping, but back references are not standard in ERE. In BRE, grouping with with \(...\) and back references with \1/\2... | (alternation) is a ERE-only operator though. In any case, GNU grep supports all of grouping, back reference and alternation in both BRE and ERE as extensions over the standard. In any case, the default regexps for GNU find are those of ancient versions of GNU emacs, not grep.

Thanks @StéphaneChazelas.  I've updated the question with the ls | egrep | sed output. I was prepared for PCRE to not be supported, but I thought I was enabling ERE when I ran -regextype egrep.

general remarks: the whole folder /tmp/.debrief must be safe to delete as long as the program using it is  not running, or it's very much abusing the /tmp directory.

Is /tmp/.debrief possibly a symlink?

Typo in the question: you say div\debmeta when you mean div|debmeta.

Monday morning, and it's working.  Voting to close my own question as 'not reproducible'.  Must have been a typo that I kept making over and over.
